# How to generate page numbers using javascript?

Tags: javascript, pagination, paginator

How do I generate page numbers for a multi page data set using javascript?

Consider there are 55 pages. I want to generate page numbers like this

`1 2 3 4 5 ..... 55 next`

Which is rather similar to the Stackoverflow questions pager

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Jquery pagination plugin](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm), you can use it directly or check its source to get an idea for own custom pagination script.

Hope this helps, Sinan.